# Cleaning up data in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have very large data set that's broken out a bit too far and I need to pull it back.

Say for example the data is a DVD box set. The initial catalogers added each episode as an entry (but ID'd it by the season). However, we only care about the individual DVDs from the box set.

I'd like to write a query that groups these entries by the ID numbers and concat the titles into a blob field.

That is...

Given a record set like this below...

```
| ID        | Title
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------
| 1234      | Batman: Season 1, Episode 6: "Batman Is Riled"                                                                                                         | 
| 1234      | Batman: Season 1, Episode 7: "Instant Freeze"                                                                                                          | 
| 5678      | Batman: Season 2, Episode 9: "The Greastest Mother of Them All"                                                                                        | 
| 5678      | Batman: Season 2, Episode 7: "The Spell of Tut"                                                                                                        | 
| 5678      | Batman: Season 2, Episode 6: "Barbecued Batman?"                                                                                                       | 
| 5678      | Batman: Season 2, Episode 3: "Hot Off the Griddle"                                                                                                     |   
| 9012      | Batman: Season 3, Episode 24: "The Joker's Flying Saucer"                                                                                              | 
| 9012      | Batman: Season 3, Episode 25: "The Entracing Dr. Cassandra"                                                                                            | 
| 9012      | Batman: Season 3, Episode 26: "Minerva, Mayhem and Millionaires"
```

I'd like to convert this into a newer structure such as

```
| ID        | Title  | Description
| 1234      | Batman |Batman: Season 1, Episode 6: "Batman Is Riled"; Batman: Season 1, Episode 7: "Instant Freeze"                                                                                                          | 
| 5678      | Batman |Batman: Season 2, Episode 9: "The Greastest Mother of Them; Batman: Season 2, Episode 7: "The Spell of Tut"; Batman: Season 2, Episode 6: "Barbecued Batman?"; Batman: Season 2, Episode 3: "Hot Off the Griddle"                                                                                                     |   
| 9012      | Batman |Batman: Season 3, Episode 24: "The Joker's Flying Saucer"; Batman: Season 3, Episode 25: "The Entracing Dr. Cassandra"; Batman: Season 3, Episode 26: "Minerva, Mayhem and Millionaires"
```

Is this possible in mysql or do I need to pull it out into a spread sheet?

Comment: Do you know NF? http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Comment: look at the group concat function http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/

Comment: in what programming language?

Comment: @lxer I'm tyring to do this in pure mysql

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Sir, put that in the answers column so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) will do the trick

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46296/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE dvd
    (`ID` int, `Title` varchar(64))
;

INSERT INTO dvd
    (`ID`, `Title`)
VALUES
    (1234, 'Batman: Season 1, Episode 6: "Batman Is Riled"'),
    (1234, 'Batman: Season 1, Episode 7: "Instant Freeze"'),
    (5678, 'Batman: Season 2, Episode 9: "The Greastest Mother of Them All"'),
    (5678, 'Batman: Season 2, Episode 7: "The Spell of Tut"'),
    (5678, 'Batman: Season 2, Episode 6: "Barbecued Batman?"'),
    (5678, 'Batman: Season 2, Episode 3: "Hot Off the Griddle"'),
    (9012, 'Batman: Season 3, Episode 24: "The Joker''s Flying Saucer"'),
    (9012, 'Batman: Season 3, Episode 25: "The Entracing Dr. Cassandra"'),
    (9012, 'Batman: Season 3, Episode 26: "Minerva, Mayhem and Millionaires"')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select id, substring(title,1,locate(":",title)-1) title, 
group_concat(title SEPARATOR ";") as description
from dvd
group by ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46296/5/0)**:

```
|   ID |  title |                                                                                                                                                                                                         description |
|------|--------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1234 | Batman |                                                                                                                        Batman: Season 1, Episode 6: "Batman Is Riled";Batman: Season 1, Episode 7: "Instant Freeze" |
| 5678 | Batman | Batman: Season 2, Episode 9: "The Greastest Mother of Them All";Batman: Season 2, Episode 7: "The Spell of Tut";Batman: Season 2, Episode 6: "Barbecued Batman?";Batman: Season 2, Episode 3: "Hot Off the Griddle" |
| 9012 | Batman |                              Batman: Season 3, Episode 24: "The Joker's Flying Saucer";Batman: Season 3, Episode 25: "The Entracing Dr. Cassandra";Batman: Season 3, Episode 26: "Minerva, Mayhem and Millionaires" |
```